# [] character in front of WebSocket message?

Tags: php, javascript, json, websocket

I'm playing around with websockets and I noticed that when my server sends a message to the client, there is an extra '[]' character in front of the message. This is preventing JS from parsing the json properly.

Any idea what this character is???

Comment: OK I just found that it is actually part of a library i am using. For some reason the author is wrapping around the string with chr(0) and chr(255) in PHP. Anyone know what is the point of this?

Comment: May i ask, which ws server you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to an HTTP-like handshake between client and server, each message from starts with '\x0' and ends with '\xff'.

In future drafts of the WebSockets protocol (beyond 03/76), the framing delimiters have been replaced by framing which includes a leading length and no trailing special character.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution: by js, just use the replace function of javascript
example, assume msg is the string returned by websocket.message function

```
msg = $.parseJSON(msg.data.replace('\0', ''));
```

Or, without jQuery:

```
msg = JSON.parse(msg.data.replace('\0', ''));
```

Hope someone will find this helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It's not ok that YOU (Client) see this \x00 delimiter in your msg!

Normally your msg looks like this \x00 MSG \xFF. \x00 and \xFF will be cut on client side, so there must be a problem on server side... look, that you dont wrap twice your msg!?

Comment: You're probably right. But I'm using someones library to do the socket server, so I didn't really dig too deep to find the root cause. I like your enthusiasm so I voted you up anyway.

Answer (score 0):

those are delimiting characters to mark the beginning and the end.

Best

Raffael